# Android Symbol cannot find error

Tags: android, find, symbols

I have a written an Android code for a simple PHP login form, but I am getting the following errors as below, please help he out what the mistake I have made.
PS:I am new to Android.

```
Error:(34, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable UserLocalStore
Error:(37, 38) error: incompatible types: <null> cannot be converted to int
Error:(38, 31) error: non-static method storeUserData(User) cannot be referenced from a static context
Error:(39, 31) error: non-static method setUserLoggedIn(boolean) cannot be referenced from a static context
```

My code is as follows,

```
Login.java
package techcarty.techcarty.com.techcarty;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

Button bLogin;
EditText etMobileno, etPassword;
TextView register,fpass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    etMobileno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMobileno);
    etPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    bLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
    register=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.register);
    fpass=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fpass);

    UserLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);
    bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            User user = new User(null, null);
            UserLocalStore.storeUserData(user);
            UserLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(true);
            }
        });

    }


public void onClick(View iq) {

    switch (iq.getId()) {
        case R.id.register:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Register.class));
            break;
        case R.id.fpass:
            //toast text begins
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Still need to develop";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
            //toast text ends
            break;



        }
    }
}
```

Additionally my UserLocalStore.java file contains

```
 package techcarty.techcarty.com.techcarty;
    package techcarty.techcarty.com.techcarty;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
        import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button bLogin;
    EditText etMobileno, etPassword;
    TextView register,fpass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        etMobileno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMobileno);
        etPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        bLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        register=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.register);
        fpass=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fpass);

        UserLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);
        bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                User user = new User(null, null);
                UserLocalStore.storeUserData(user);
                UserLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(true);
            }
        });

    }


    public void onClick(View iq) {

        switch (iq.getId()) {
            case R.id.register:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Register.class));
                break;
            case R.id.fpass:
                //toast text begins
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Still need to develop";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
                //toast text ends
                break;



        }
    }
}

l
import android.content.Context;l
import android.content.SharedPreferences;l
l
/**l
 * Created by SI on 3/18/2016.l
 */l
public class UserLocalStore {l
    public static final String SP_NAME = "userDetailesl";
    SharedPreferences userLocalDatabase;l
l
    public UserLocalStore(Context context){l
        userLocalDatabase = context.getSharedPreferencles(SP_NAME, 0);
l
l
    }l
    public  void storeUserData(User user){l
        SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDlatabase.edit();
        spEditor.putString("name", user.name);l
        spEditor.putInt("age",user.mobno);l
        spEditor.putString("password", user.password);l
        spEditor.commit();l
    }l
    public User getLoggedInUser(){l
        String name = userLocalDatabase.getString("namle", "");
        int mobno = userLocalDatabase.getInt("mobno", l-1);
        String password = userLocalDatabase.getString(l"password", "");
l
        User storedUser = new User(name, password, moblno);
        return storedUser;l
    }l
    public  void setUserLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn){l
        SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDlatabase.edit();
        spEditor.putBoolean("loggedIn", loggedIn);l
        spEditor.commit();l
    }l
    public boolean getUserLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn){l
        if(userLocalDatabase.getBoolean("loggedIn", fallse) == true){
            return true;l
        }else{l
            return false;l
        }l
l
    }l
    public void clearUserData(){l
        SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDlatabase.edit();
        spEditor.clear();l
        spEditor.commit();l
    }l
}l
l
```

Comment: Additionally my UserLocalSore.java file contains this,

Comment: You are missing a variable name `UserLocalStore userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Give variable name for UserLocalStore while creating object